# till the time usage

Tags: grammar

"we would be using xyz till the time abc is being setup."

is this correct usage? how can i draft it more formally? please suggest.

scenario : abc is currently unavailable and during the time its being set up we would like to request xyz for our use.

here xyz,abc are just for representation purpose.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: edited, please check

Comment: If you are waiting for the setting-up of abc to be completed, why not use _while_?